# Write operation being executed in JTextArea

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I've wrote an app that creates graph images based on a list of x : f(x). At the gui, it should show what pair is being written on the graph at the moment, but the JTextArea only show the messages after the loop that generates the image is done. How can the messages be shown at real time?

I've thought on using multi thread, but still didn't worked.

below is the code of graph generator:

```
public static void processFile(String filename, String currentDir){
    File file = new File(filename);

    LogWindow logWindow = showLogWindow();

    String line, function;
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> dataSet = null;

    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        logWindow.log("Starting processing of file " + file.getName());
        skipHeader(reader, Constantes.HEADER_LINES);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            if(line.startsWith("function ")){
                function = line.substring(25, 35).trim();

                if(dataSet != null){
                    logWindow.log("Graph of function " + function + " created.");
                    Graph demo = new Graph(dataSet);
                    demo.writeAsPNG(currentDir + File.separator + function + ".png");
                }

                dataSet = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
            }else{                  
                int x = Integer.valueOf(line.substring(20,25).trim());
                int fX = Integer.valueOf(line.substring(25,30).trim());
                dataSet.put(x, fx);
                logWindow.log("Adding values of x = " + x + " and f(x) = " + fX);
            }
        }

        //Writing last set of data
        logWindow.log("Graph of function " + function + " created.");
        Graph demo = new Graph(dataSet);
        demo.writeAsPNG(currentDir + File.separator + function + ".png");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //TODO log this better
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO log this better
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

And this is the code of the LogWindow class

```
public class LogWindow extends JPanel {
private JTextArea log;

public LogWindow() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
            log = new JTextArea(5,40);
            log.setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
            log.setEditable(false);
            JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane(log);
            add(logScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void log(String message){
        LogThread t = new LogThread(log, message);
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Log this better
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

class LogThread extends Thread{
JTextArea log;
String message;

public LogThread(JTextArea log, String message) {
    this.log = log;
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    log.append(message + Constantes.lineBreak);
    log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());        
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably need to update the `TextArea` in the Swing thread using `invokeLater()` - see the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your code is incompleted, post an SSCCE/MVCE

  ---
- you have an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), Swing is single threaded and all updates to already visible [AWT/Swing GUI must be on EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- quick fix by wrap `log.append(message + Constantes.lineBreak);` into `invokeLater()`
- no idea for why reason is there `t.join();`

---

- (repeatly called) code line `log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());` should be replaced with (works only in the case that all updates are done on EDT) single definition for `JTextArea`/event. `JTextComponent`

.

```
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) log.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

Comment: At the end, I changed the quick fix for the SwingWorker approach, as suggested in [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html)